# Cloth simulation drive rig rendering issues

Tags: rendering, rigging, cloth-simulation

**Goal**: Create rig with springy bones for i.e. auto belly fat simulation.

**Issue**: When rendering I'm unable to see spring effect on bones that are driven by objects with is driven by cloth simulation. In blender window it works correctly.

**Set up**:

- create vertex line (I used extension "Add Mesh: Extra objects") with i.e. 3 vertexes (Shift+A -> Mesh -> Single vert -> Add single ver)
- add Cloth simulation to that vertex object
- add new Vertex group and add all vertexes
- set vertex weights to i.e. 1.0 -> 0.7 -> 0.4.
- add new Vertex group and add only last vertex
- in Cloth simulation set Pin Group to group with all vertex
- bake simulation

Bones:

- add bones i.e. 3 bones i.e. from bottom to top 2 bones one bone to left
- on "left bone" (belly) add "Copy transform" and point to empty that that has "Copy location" to vertex group with last vertex in it

Set up image:

[image]

Viewport video:

[image]

Rendered video:

[image]

This all is based on tutorial for 2.79 i.e.:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WppjPyrDon4

Any idea why this happens ?

[Blend file download](https://megaup.net/28J5o/springBonesTest.7z)